# how to reset array order after filtering in php

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

```
$p2 = array_filter($p);
var_dump($p2);
```

I have a $p array which has `''` values. I have deleted them using `array_filter()` function. But I also want to re-order/reset indices.

`$p` array contents

```
  0 => string '' (length=0)
  1 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => string '' (length=0)
  3 => string '' (length=0)
  4 => string '' (length=0)
  5 => string '' (length=0)
  6 => string '' (length=0)
  7 => string '' (length=0)
  8 => string '123' (length=3)
  9 => string '20130' (length=5)
  10 => string '' (length=0)
```

After filtering the new array is as the following:

`$p2` array contents

```
  8 => string '123' (length=3)
  9 => string '20130' (length=5)
```

I want `$p2`

```
  0 => string '123' (length=3)
  1 => string '20130' (length=5)
```

Transferring elements to a new array would be a solution. I will go with that way if there is not faster method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php):

```
$p2 = array_values($p2);
```

or in your case you could do both directly:

```
$p = array_values(array_filter($p));
```

which will keep the same array name and filter AND reindex the array at once